# How to push specific users in Mongo Collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on an app in `Meteor`, let's call it meetups. I've already done basic crud and now I'm stucked with request action when a user sends a request for invite for a meetup (I use `accounts-password` package to handle auth, if it means anything). I want to show meetup's owner which users would like to visit this meetup, so it's how I designed it:
I created a 'Join' button in my template and it works perfectly when I make an event in my controller like this:

```
'click .join': function(event) {
    var params = {
      user: Meteor.userId(),
      username: Meteor.user().username
    }
    toastr.success('You've send a request');
    Router.go('/meetups');
}
```

Since I handle this events fetching user's params, it's very easy to show his username, I do it like this:

```
<p>{{username}} sent a request to join your meetup</p> <button class="btn-primary btn-xs yes">Ok</button> <button class="btn-danger btn-xs no">No</button>
```

I don't want to just show this user, I want to let meetup's owner also manage requests (that's why I created two buttons). Basically, it's just a simple crud, isn't it? That's why I created a new Mongo collection called 'Guests' and my `'invite event` now looks like this:

```
'click .join': function(event) {
        var params = {
          user: Meteor.userId(),
          username: Meteor.user().username
        }
    Meteor.call('join', params);
    toastr.success('Ok');
    Router.go('/meetups');
}
```

In case I use `call` function, I have a method to handle it:

```
Meteor.methods({
    'join': function (params) {
        Guests.insert(params);
    }
});
```

I also created anothe template called `guests`:

```
<template name="guests">
  {{#each guests}}
    <p>{{username}} sent a request to join your meetup</p> <button class="btn-primary btn-xs yes">Ok</button> <button class="btn-danger btn-xs no">No</button>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

and included it in my meetups template like this: `{{> guests}}`.
As you can understand since that I see no usernames. I used an iteration through `guests` collection and try to fetch `username` because it worked just fine withound defining a separate collection.
So my question is how the heck can I push specific users (in my case those who clicked `join` button) and show their usernames? Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: `var params = { user: Meteor.userId(), username: Meteor.user().username }` - you are calling 2 functions, instead you can call it only once: `var user = Meteor.user(); var params = { user: user._id, username: user.username }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<template name="guests">
  {{#each guests}}
    <p>{{username}} sent a request to join your meetup</p> <button class="btn-primary btn-xs yes">Ok</button> <button class="btn-danger btn-xs no">No</button>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

How about add `guests helper` in `guests template`?
You didn't define it.

```
Template.guests.helpers({
    guests: function () {
        return Guests.find();
    }
});
```

Comment: Also you need to be sure that your 'join' method is correct and works. Use console (meteor mongo -> db.guests.find().fetch()) and check.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
Not having a special helper to fetch all the guests was the main issue with my code